# How to get the icon for an Android permission?

Tags: android, permissions

The XML spec for `<permission>` and `<permission-group>` refers to an icon which you see in Settings | App info | Permissions.

If I already have the permission an app needs in the from of a string from querying the PackageInfo, for example "android.permission.INTERNET", how can I get the associated permission and permission-group icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, following approach should work:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
PermissionInfo info = pm.getPermissionInfo("PERMISSION_NAME", OPTIONAL_FLAGS);
int drawableResource = info.icon;
```

There's also a method in PackageManager called `getPermissionGroupInfo`.

Comment: icon is always 0. What was the value of OPTIONAL_FLAGS?

Comment: Just check the documentation and fill in `OPTIONAL_FLAG` with your needs.

Comment: Which value did you use? I used GET_META_DATA since [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) says, "Use GET_META_DATA to retrieve any meta-data associated with the permission." And icon was 0

Comment: Yes, i used the same one. For which permission are you trying to get the icon? also take care of that Android 6 uses another permission system than previous android versions.

Comment: Yes, I need icons for some permissions my app needs in Android 6. Let me figure things out tomorrow. It's 11 p.m. in my time zone now

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev Did you find a solution for the icon? For me it's always 0.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab5, yes, I did. Please see my code below. Tested on Nexus 6 with Android 6.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code.

```
package sample.com.sample_android;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PermissionGroupInfo;
import android.content.pm.PermissionInfo;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ANDROID = "android";
    private PackageManager mPackageManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPackageManager = getPackageManager();

        String permission = Manifest.permission.INTERNET;

        Drawable drawable = getPermissionDrawable(permission);
        ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(permission);
    }

    @Nullable
    private Drawable getPermissionDrawable(String permission) {
        Drawable drawable = null;
        try {
            PermissionInfo permissionInfo = mPackageManager.getPermissionInfo(permission, 0);
            PermissionGroupInfo groupInfo = mPackageManager.getPermissionGroupInfo(permissionInfo.group, 0);
            drawable = mPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ANDROID).getDrawable(groupInfo.icon);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException|Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

[image]